# Handling metacharacters in search strings

Tags: bash, variables, grep, user-input, special-characters

I have a user input that would be used in a search string that may contain a metacharacter

For e.g. C# or C++

my grep command in a function was:

```
grep -E "$1|$2" test.txt
```

under direct replacement:

```
grep -E "C\+\+|testWord" test.txt
grep -E "C\#|testWord" test.txt
```

the first caught the lines fine but not the second.
Strangely, # was completely ignored.
Without direct replacement, both catch anything with c followed by testWord instead of c++ and c# respectively

I've tried handling it using sed

```
$temp = `echo $1 | sed 's/[\#\!\&\;\`\"\'\|\*\?\~\<\>\^\(\)\[\]\{\}\$\+\\]/\\&/g'`
```

but it doesn't work right.
Or is there any other way to handle user input with metacharacters?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you getting the user input? As command line arguments or via the `read` command?

Comment: Interesting. Using your new examples, C++ is the one that is giving me the trouble where it seems to be C# that's problematic for you. I found that using **both** quotes and backslashes helped: `grep -E "C\+\+"` as does using regular grep with an escaped pipe without escaping the pluses: `grep "C++\|C#"`

Comment: Regarding your sed example, you don't normally want a dollar sign on a variable name on the left hand side of an assignment (unless you're doing indirection).

Comment: the two variables need to be in the same line to get found and in that sequence $1 first then $2

someone pointed awk may work, think ill go read up on that. hope thats the right way to go

btw, thanks for helping me out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are passing the input as arguments to the script

```
#!/bin/bash

input1="$1"
input2="$2"
while read -r line
do
    case "$line" in
        *$input1*|*$input2* ) echo "found: $line";;
    esac
done  <"BooksDB.txt
```

"

output

```
$ cat file
this is  a line
this line has C++ and C#
this line has only C++ and that's it
this line has only C# and that's it
this is end line Caa

$ ./shell.sh C++ C#
found: this line has C++ and C#
found: this line has only C++ and that's it
found: this line has only C# and that's it
```

if you are getting input from read

```
read -p "Enter input1:" input1
read -p "Enter input2:" input2
while read -r line
do
    case "$line" in
        *$input1|*$input2* ) echo "found: $line";;
    esac
done <"BooksDB.txt"
```

Comment: I've tried with two variables with the following code:

    fileContents = cat BookDB.txt; 
    case "*$1*$2*" in 
    *fileContents* ) echo "found!";;
    esac

couldn't find anything at all
I was passing theh input as arguments to the script

Sorry I don't know how to format code in the comments. It looks pretty messy.. >.<

Comment: see new edit. no need for cat. just do a while read loop using the shell.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$ testfun1(){ echo "foo $1" | grep "$1"; }
$ testfun1 C#
foo C#
$ testfun2(){ read a; echo "bar $a" | grep "$a"; }
$ testfun2
C#
bar C#
```

**Edit:**

You might try this form without `-E`:

```
$ testfun3(){ grep "$1\|$2" test.txt; }
$ testfun3 C++ awk
something about C++
blah awk blah
$ testfun3 C# sed
blah sed blah
the text containing C#
$ testfun3 C# C++
something about C++
the text containing C#
```

Comment: It does work but not with two variables.
I realised my grep statement was wrong. It's corrected now but still is unable to handle strings with metacharacters :(

Answer (score 0):

Just quote all the grep metacharacters in $1 and $2 before adding them to your grep expression.

Something like this:

```
quoted1=`echo "$1" | sed -e 's/\([]\.?^${}+*[]\)/\\\\\1/g'`
quoted2=`echo "$2" | sed -e 's/\([]\.?^${}+*[]\)/\\\\\1/g'`
grep -E "$quoted1\|$quoted2" test.txt
```

ought to work.  Adjust the metachar list to suit.  Handling | is a little tricky because backslashing *makes* it special, but since we're already backslashing backslashes I think it's safe.

Comment: i noticed two [] in the enclosed \\( and \\), what is the purpose of adding the second one? and in the replacement string, i only understood the purpose of 3 \,  2 to make the first back slash that would be appended in front, the last one to represent \1. what would the last two be for?