# detecting dangerous unix command line metacharacters

Tags: php, linux, unix, web

I'm working on a web application that has some api calls that send arguments for command line operations. For example, (using jquery), an api call like:

```
$.get('/api',{
function:function_1,
data:data
},funcion(){},'text')
```

might execute a command line like:

```
php a.php data
```

in that case, if the content of data was `"whatever;rm -rf *;"`, two commands would be executed

1. `php a.php watever;`
2. `rm -rf *;`

And I don't want to take that risk.

My problem is not detecting when a character is part of the data string, my problem is knowing which chars should I look for?

I'm adding a list of shell command metacharacters. Please specify which characters are risky and which combination of characters (if any) are risky.

---

NOTE:
Taken from: http://www.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fslcourse/unix_intro/shell.html

The shell meta characters include:

\ / < > ! $ % ^ & * | { } [ ] " ' ` ~ ;

NOTE 2: There may be other characters, please, if you know another add it or comment and I'll add it.

NOTE 3: My problem is similar to what might happen with sql injection. when someone adds hidden querys inside search text-boxes, but in my case, the problem is with shell commands. To prevent sql injection you can look at [this](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: In case it hepls somebody, this question might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135558/handling-metacharacters-in-search-strings

Comment: See as well: [PHP - What's the difference between escapeshellarg and escapeshellcmd?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1881582/367456).

Comment: What function are you using php-side to execute the command? Could you  replace whatever it is with a `pcntl_fork()/pcntl_exec()` pair?

Comment: Mostly git commands, but some are executed using ssh2 on other servers. The system updates the code in many servers at the same time. The problem is that I need the action status so I already do some extra things like. `cmd data 2>/tmp/tmp2 1>/tmp/tmp1; echo $? 1>/tmp/tmpstatus;cat /tmp/tmp1;echo %DIFF%;cat /tmp/tmp2;echo %DIFF%;cat /tmp/tmpstatus;rm /tmp/tmp1 ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly what `escapeshellarg` is for.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php

Answer (score 3):

You are much better off trying to define what characters *are allowed* in the input, and check that the input only contains those, i.e. a "white-list" approach.

Comment: I'll apply this with some calls, with others, I can't.