# Terminal passing arguments from variable containing whitespace

Tags: php, shell, ubuntu

In terminal how to pass a string as param that contains whitespace . It actually skips the part coming after whitespace and only takes the first word .

```
$word = 'soccer ball'
shell_exec('casperjs test.js --word='.$word);
```

So how can I escape the whitespace it only runs this command

```
casperjs test.js --word=soccer
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php

Comment: I have edited the question and want you to post this as an answer since this is the most price way of doing .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For cases like the one you describe (there are other special characters next to space in shell), PHP has the [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg) function:

```
$word    = 'soccer ball';
$command = sprintf('casperjs test.js --word=%s', escapeshellarg($word));
$result  = shell_exec($command);
```

I takes care to preserve the value of `$word` as *one* argument:

```
casperjs test.js --word='soccer ball'
```

See as well:

- [detecting dangerous unix command line metacharacters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964398/detecting-dangerous-unix-command-line-metacharacters)

Answer (score 2):

Try enclosing it in quotes:

```
casperjs test.js --word="soccer ball"
```

Comment: Or in his case `shell_exec('casperjs test.js --word="'.$word."');`

Comment: Thank you all but i think there is a typo above