# PHP executes Python but no output

Tags: php, python, unix

I want to run a Python script from PHP via [`system`](http://php.net/system) with some arguments. My PHP doesn't throw any errors and `$retval` is 1. But I don't see any generated output file `$f1` in the current directory. Is there a chance the output file goes somewhere else?

```
$outp1 = system("python plain.py {$url1} {$f1}", $retval);
```

Comment: What happens when you use `shell_exec`?

Comment: Please see [Terminal passing arguments from variable containing whitespace](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12925034/367456) - It looks like you do not really care about creating a safe command string, so it might be that you are not passing to the command what you think.

Comment: You need to debug the command, assign it to a variable first so you can print and review it. In case you're interested if the command itself generates error output to  [*stderr*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams), please see [PHP StdErr after Exec()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2320608/367456) for multiple ways to achieve that.

Comment: It seems to work with a simpler script which just prints the time. $o=system("python t.py",$retval);
echo $o;
echo $retval;
echo "python plain.py {$url1} {$f1}";
$outp1=system("python plain.py {$url1} {$f1}",$retval);
echo $outp1;
echo $retval; as you can see I print the command, output and retval; plus I checked the folder for the output file $f1

Comment: There are no white spaces within string variables

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer now, I needed to set permissions to 777 so that apache can write to the folder.